# Python 3.5 typed NamedTuple syntax produces SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.5, type-hinting, python-typing

I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error when I try the new typed `namedtuple` syntax:

```
class Employee(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    id: int
```

in Python 3.5.2 even though according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) it should be valid from 3.5+ onwards. Am I missing something? I've imported `NamedTuple` from `typing` in the code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The syntax to declare the types for the `name` and `id` fields you are using requires [Python 3.6 or up](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-526-syntax-for-variable-annotations). Python 3.5 does not support the variable-level type hints required.

From the [`typing.NamedTuple` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple):

> Changed in version 3.6: Added support for [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) variable annotation syntax.

Use the *backwards compatible syntax* also included in the documentation:

```
Employee = NamedTuple('Employee', [('name', str), ('id', int)])
```

so listing the field names as `(name, type)` tuples.

If you are using Python 3.5, you may want to switch to the [Python 3.5 version of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) instead (there is a selector in the top-left corner, or you can just replace the `3` in the URL with `3.5`).

Comment: huh at the top of the docs it says "New in version 3.5." EDIT oh i see... that's per section.

Comment: @daj: yes, the `typing` module is new in Python 3.5. The additional syntax to annotate variables (like used here to declare `name` as a `str` and `id` as `int`), requires Python 3.6.

Comment: @daj: if you are using Python 3.5, you can switch to the version-specific documentation instead: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple. Note the `3.5` in the URL there.