# error with python saying invalid syntax trying to create list of struct

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

In key frames in Camera resectioning, I am trying to create a list of points that appears in a frame and then try to create a list containing the corresponding points in the following frames to keep tracking the points along the video to find the K matrix between them.

I have the following class to store the points from each frame and to create a list of points for each frame and tracking them along all frames.

```
class PointsCorrespondence:
    """
    Stores the point of a specific index.
    """

    # A point is represented as (coordinate X, coordinate Y)
    Point = (float, float)

    # A point with corresponding same point is represented as (coordinates, index of the corresponding point or -1 if there is no corresponding point).
    PointWithCorrespondence = (Point, int)

    # Contains the points represented as one list of notable points for each frame.
    _pointsPerFrame : [[PointWithCorrespondence]]

    def __init__(self, pointsPerFrame : [[PointWithCorrespondence]]):
        self._pointsPerFrame = pointsPerFrame
```

when I try to run this code to store the points inside it, I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 4, in
>   
>       import pointTracking   File "/home/k/Desktop/CV/project/insertc/project12345/pointTracking.py",
>   line 17
>
> ```
> _pointsPerFrame : [[PointWithCorrespondence]]
>                 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

actually I don't know why I got that error, and I tried many things to check the python syntax styles.

I am using python 3.4

Comment: Are you trying to define *types* there, or *values*? It's quite confusing. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I use python 3.4.3 default version on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: this is just the initialization of the variables I will use to store my point in

Comment: Well: 1. that's a *class attribute*, which you don't actually need to "initialise" to set an *instance attribute*; and 2. you seem to be mixing up assigning *values* to those attributes (e.g. `(float, float)` is a two-tuple literal with the built-in float class as both elements) with specifying *types*, so please clarify the expected behaviour. Is your teammate also using 3.4.x?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002596/python-3-5-typed-namedtuple-syntax-produces-syntaxerror

Comment: as you said, he uses python 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable annotations are new in Python 3.6, see e.g. [what's new](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep526) and [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations); you will need to upgrade to use this syntax. Note that you're assigning *values*, not annotating *types*, to the other two class attributes; this is presumably unintentional.